# Add transpose to excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im currently working on a larger project where i will recive alot of word documents that i want to transform into an excell sheet and then add to an Access database, the first part I have figured out by using this vba:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
        TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If
    With .tables(TableNo)
        'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
    End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

However i need a way to transpose the table without keeping the original data, is there a way i can add any sort of vba code to the existing code in order to combine the two jobs?

Comment: Did u try to replace the iRow and iCol, Cells(iCol, iRow)  = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below code, and check if this is what you need

```
    With .tables(TableNo)
    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            Cells(iCol, iRow) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End With
```